# AWS API Gateway returning { "message": "Internal Server Error" } in HTTP proxy integration

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I've been fighting this problem for two days now. I have a HTTP API Gateway in AWS where I have different routes with a HTTP proxy integration. For example:

'https://apigateway.domain.com/service/path' routes to 'https://service.domain.com/path'.

'apigateway.domain.com' is a custom domain name configured on the API Gateway and 'service.domain.com' is a domain which A dns entry is the elastic IP of an EC2 instance with ubuntu and nginx on it.

Until today we had different routes all pointing to some EC2 instances and our main web app in Spain. We are configuring another countries in which we have to offer service. We launched some EC2 instances for it in us-west-1 region, assigned an elastic IP and created its domain names.

The problem is we do a request to apigateway.domain.com/country/service/path and it answers with 500 status code:

```
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error" 
}
```

If I do the same request directly to the domain name of the EC2 instance it answers me with 200 status code.

The request to the api gateway is not reaching the ec2 machine as I cannot find the request in nginx logs.
I've tried to debug this situation with Cloudwatch and X-ray but I have not found enough information:

> { "accountId": "********", "apiId": "*********", "authorizerError":
> "-", "basePathMatched": "(none)", "fullDomainName": "*********",
> "msgString": " "Internal Server Error"", "httpMethod": "GET",
> "integStatus": "200", "requestId":"flJRogGhliAEPUA=", "ip":
> "138.199.37.68", "requestTime":"19/May/2021:14:36:32 +0000",
> "httpMethod":"GET","routeKey":"ANY /mx/staging/tmc/{proxy+}",
> "status":"500","protocol":"HTTP/1.1", "responseLength":"35", "error":
> "Internal Server Error", "errorResponseType": "INTEGRATION_FAILURE",
> "integrationErrorMsg": "-", "authorizerError": "-" , "integErrorMsg":
> "-", "status": "500" }

[image]

remote refers to domain name of ec2 instance.

I've checked multiple times security groups and it seems to be good (copied from the ones of Frankfurt region where we have our principal ec2 instances for Spain). We have an EC2 instance in this region and the api gateway is correctly making the proxy to it, so we suspect it is some bad configuration before the request reaches nginx server once it has reached the machine itself (i don't know, iptables or something like that, I'm not pro linux hehe).

If someone has fighted with something similar please let us know as we are already blocked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching AWS support team it turned out to be a problem with the SSL certificate on the end nginx server (bad format).
They told me they will improve this error message because it was not so descriptive.